# Class "PhpMyAdmin\Properties\Plugins\ExportPluginProperties" not found in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\Export\ExportCodegen.php:67

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Por alguna razón en mi phpmyadmin me aparece este error al momento de importar o exportar una base de datos, este es el feedback:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpMyAdmin\Properties\Plugins\ExportPluginProperties" not found in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\Export\ExportCodegen.php:67 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\Export\ExportCodegen.php(44): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportCodegen->setProperties() #1 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins.php(177): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportCodegen->__construct() #2 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins.php(101): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins::getPlugins('export', 'libraries/class...', Array) #3 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Controllers\Database\ExportController.php(145): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins::getExport('database', false) #4 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Routing.php(187): PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\ExportController->index(Array) #5 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute('/database/expor...', Object(FastRoute\Dispatcher\GroupCountBased), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #6 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\Export\ExportCodegen.php on line 67>

Sinceramente no entiendo la situación y me ayudaría demasiado si alguien supiese la respuesta a este problema. (También ya revisé el archivo y me dispuse a buscar la clase en todo el xampp)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta limpiar la caché del navegador y remover las cookies de PhpMyAdmin.

Haz lo siguiente:

1. Abre PhpMyAdmin en el navegador
2. Presiona F12 para abrir las developer tools
3. Ve a Aplicacion y limpia todas las cookies y caché
4. Refresca la página con F12 > click derecho en el icono de recarga > "vaciar la caché y volver a cargar de manera forzada"

Comment: Hice todo al pie de la letra, pero no se por qué me sigue apareciendo el mismo error. Qué significa como tal ese error?

Comment: Se refiere a que hay un problema con las librerias, esas usando xampp para todo esto ?